# Cant add function to my controller (Angular 1)

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

Edit: Ive solved it. There was a gruntfile.js in the root of the project. Had never heard of it before, Googled it, ran it, and now it works. Stupid. Anyways, thanks for the effort guys!

I just want to preface this; this is not my project, I am just trying to add to it, and the original maker is not available. I have only worked with AngularJS for three weeks in a course I went to and the structure was exactly like how AngularJS recommend, not like this project.

I am trying to add two buttons for a modal popup with subscription information. It contains both general sub-info and a history table. The buttons are there to flip between sub-info and history. So I've written a function just to try it out. Its called "toggleMobileDetailsInfoHistoryModule".
This is the html, its only got five scripts like this, and nothing else, and this is the one I am working with:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="MobileSubscriptionDetailModal">
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="cancel()">&times;</button>
    <h4>{{"mobileSubscriptionResource.title"|translate}}</h4><br />
    <button ng-click="toggleMobileDetailsInfoHistoryModule()">{{"mobileSubscriptionResource.history"|translate}}</button>
    <button ng-click="toggleMobileDetailsInfoHistoryModule()">{{"mobileSubscriptionResource.info"|translate}}</button>
</div>
<div ng-if="showInfoModule" class="modal-body">
    <form role="form" name="form" novalidate>

    </form>
</div>
<div ng-if="showHistoryModule" ng-include=" 'pages/history.html' "></div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary pull-left" ng-click="edit(mobileSubscription)" ng-show="mobileSubscription.IsOperation">{{'commonResource.edit'|translate}}</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger pull-left" ng-click="delete(mobileSubscription)" ng-show="mobileSubscription.IsOperation">{{'commonResource.remove'|translate}}</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancel()" data-translate="commonResource.cancel"></button>
</div>
```

So, I want to toggle between the form that contains sub-info and the div where I include the table from 'pages/history.html'

this is an excerpt with relevant info from the subController:

```
app.controller("mobileSubscriptionController", ["$scope", "mobileSubscriptionService", "$rootScope", "$modal", "tools", "statusService", "constantService",
"statusFilterService", "columnFilterService",
function ($scope, mobileSubscriptionService, $rootScope, $modal, tools, statusService, constantService, statusFilterService, columnFilterService) {


    $scope.detail = function (mobileSubscription) {
        var detail = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'MobileSubscriptionDetailModal',
            controller: mobileSubscriptionDetailCtrl,
            backdrop: 'static',
            resolve: { mobileSubscription: function () { return mobileSubscription; } }
        });

        detail.result.then(function () {
            initMobileSubscription();
        }, function (error) {
            tools.error(error);
            });
    };

}]);
```

and further down in the same file:

```
var mobileSubscriptionDetailCtrl = ["$scope", "$rootScope", "$modal", "$modalInstance", "mobileSubscription", "historyService", "tools",
function ($scope, $rootScope, $modal, $modalInstance, mobileSubscription, historyService, tools) {

    $scope.toggleMobileDetailsInfoHistoryModule = function () {
        alert("inside!");
        if ($scope.showInfoModule) {
            $scope.showHistoryModule = false;
        } else {
            $scope.showHistoryModule = true;
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.close();
    };
}];
```

Now, I've tried ng-if, ng-show. The Booleans work though. ng-click="showHistoryModule = !showHistoryModule" it works. But I need a function so it can be more complex.
I've tried using the "$modalInstance.close();" from the function underneath inside my function (dosent work/close the modal). I've tried using app.factory above app.controller and put the function in there but it dosent work, alerts/console logs dont show up.. Somehow I cant seem to add functions to this page/controller.

And this is the develop.html which im working with, it contains a million scriptreferences in the head and this in the body:

```
body ng-app="app" style="background-color: #eee">
<div class="mask" ng-show="pageLoading">
    <img class="spin" src="img/loading.gif" />
</div>
<div id="wrap" ng-style="loginBackground" ng-if="!redirecting">
    <div ng-controller="alertController">
        <alert class="global-message" ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="{{alert.type}}" close="closeAlert($index)" style="z-index: 5000;position:fixed">
            <span ng-bind-html="alert.msg"></span>
        </alert>
    </div>
    <div id="header" ng-show="isShowHeader">
        <section ng-class="" ng-show="isShowMenu" data-ng-include=" 'header.html' "></section>
    </div>
    <div id="banner" class="row" style="margin-top:-18px;">
        <div class=" col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-sm-offset-1 ">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 white">
            <div ng-show="isShowHeader">
                <span class="page-title">{{pageTitle}}</span>
                <img class="pull-right img-responsive" ng-if="loginUser.clientLogo != ''" style="height: 84px;margin-right: 50px;margin-top: 20px;" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div ng-include="'sidebar.html'"></div>
        <div id="main" class="col-sm-8 container" ng-class="{true:'white',false:'login-background'}[isShowHeader]">
            <div ng-view class="main-content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<footer id="footer" ng-show="isShowHeader" ng-if="!redirecting"></footer>
```

it loads the views near the bottom in ng-view class="main-content"

This is the mobileSubscriptionview where detail() is called (in tbody).

```
<div class="row">

<div class="col-sm-12 controll table-filter">
    <div class="form-inline" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
        <div class="form-group filter-margin-right">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{'commonResource.search'|translate}}" ng-keypress="searchMobileSubscription($event)" ng-model="keyword">
                <i ng-show="loadingLocations" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn search " ng-click="search()">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search search-icon"></i>
                    </button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="display-inline filter-margin-right" ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="properties" selected-model="selectedProperties" checkboxes="true"></div>

        <div class="column-filter-position">
            <span class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="columnFilter.dropdown = !columnFilter.dropdown">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></i>
            </span>
            <div class="dropdown-menu collapse column-filter-dropdown" ng-class="{in: columnFilter.dropdown}" ng-blur="columnFilter.dropdown = false">
                <div class="checkbox form-group status-filter-padding-left uppercase-text">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="columnFilter.SelectAll" ng-click="selectAllColumnFilter(columnFilter)"> {{'commonResource.selectAll'|translate}}
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="divider"></div>
                <div ng-repeat="column in mobileSubscriptionColumns" class="column-filter checkbox form-group column-filter-padding-left">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="column.isShowColumn" ng-click="setColumnSelectAll(columnFilter)"> {{column.otherName|translate}}
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="divider"></div>
                <div class="form-inline">
                    <div class="checkbox status-filter-padding-left">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="columnFilter.rememberMyChoice"> {{'commonResource.rememberMyChoice'|translate}}
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <span class="btn btn-primary pull-right status-filter-ok" ng-disabled="isShowColumnFilterSpinner" ng-click="addColumnFilter(columnFilter)">
                        {{'commonResource.ok'|translate}}
                        <span spinner is-show="isShowColumnFilterSpinner" style="position: absolute;right: 6%;"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right uppercase-text" ng-click="add()">{{'commonResource.add'|translate}}</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12 column-filter-table div-table-min-height">
    <table class="table tablesorter-blue">
        <thead>
            <tr class="uppercase-text tablesorter-headerRow">
                <th ng-repeat="column in mobileSubscriptionColumns" ng-class="{sortable: column.sortable !== false}" ng-show="column.isShowColumn" style="text-align: left;">
                    <i ng-if="column.sortable" class="hand glyphicon {{column.direction|orderClass}}" ng-click="sort.toggle(column)"></i>
                    {{column.otherName|translate}}
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter btn-primary hand status-filter-icon" aria-hidden="true" ng-show="column.name=='MobileSubscriptionStatus.Name'" ng-click="mobileSubscriptionStatusFilter.dropdown = !mobileSubscriptionStatusFilter.dropdown"></i>
                    <div class="dropdown" ng-if="column.name=='MobileSubscriptionStatus.Name'">
                        <div class="dropdown-menu collapse status-filter status-filter-drop-down-max-height text-capitalize" ng-class="{in: mobileSubscriptionStatusFilter.dropdown}" ng-blur="mobileSubscriptionStatusFilter.dropdown = false">
                            <div class="checkbox form-group status-filter-padding-left">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="mobileSubscriptionStatusFilter.SelectAll" ng-click="selectAllStatusFilter(mobileSubscriptionStatusFilter)"> {{'commonResource.selectAll'|translate}}
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="divider"></div>
                            <div class="status-filter-content">
                                <div ng-repeat="status in mobileSubscriptionStatusFilter.statuses" class="checkbox form-group status-filter-padding-left">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="status.Checked" ng-click="setSelectAll(mobileSubscriptionStatusFilter)"> {{status.Name}}
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="divider"></div>
                            <div class="form-inline">
                                <div class="checkbox status-filter-padding-left">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="mobileSubscriptionStatusFilter.rememberMyChoice"> {{'commonResource.rememberMyChoice'|translate}}
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <span class="btn btn-primary pull-right status-filter-ok" ng-disabled="isShowStatusFilterSpinner" ng-click="addStatusFilter(mobileSubscriptionStatusFilter)">
                                    {{'commonResource.ok'|translate}}
                                    <span spinner is-show="isShowStatusFilterSpinner" style="position: absolute;right: 6%;"></span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-show="listLoading"><td colspan="7" align="center" spinner is-show="listLoading" message="{{commonResource.dataLoading|translate}}"></td></tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="mobileSubscription in mobileSubscriptions">
                <td ng-show="mobileSubscriptionColumns[0].isShowColumn"><a class="hand" ng-click="detail(mobileSubscription)">{{mobileSubscription.MobileNumber}}</a></td>
                <td ng-show="mobileSubscriptionColumns[1].isShowColumn">{{mobileSubscription.SubscriptionType.Name}}</td>
                <td ng-show="mobileSubscriptionColumns[2].isShowColumn">{{mobileSubscription.SubscriptionCategory.Name}}</td>
                <td ng-show="mobileSubscriptionColumns[3].isShowColumn">{{mobileSubscription.ContractEndDate}}</td>
                <td ng-show="mobileSubscriptionColumns[4].isShowColumn">{{mobileSubscription.Owner}}</td>
                <td ng-show="mobileSubscriptionColumns[5].isShowColumn">{{mobileSubscription.DataLimit}}</td>
                <td ng-show="mobileSubscriptionColumns[6].isShowColumn"><a ng-class="{true:'selected-item',false:'unselected-item'}[mobileSubscription.IsActive]"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></a></td>
                <td ng-show="mobileSubscriptionColumns[7].isShowColumn" title="{{mobileSubscription.Note}}">{{mobileSubscription.Note.length>10?mobileSubscription.Note.substring(0,10)+"...":mobileSubscription.Note}}</td>
                <td ng-show="mobileSubscriptionColumns[8].isShowColumn">{{mobileSubscription.MobileSubscriptionStatus.Name}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

    <div class="form-inline">
        <pagination style="display: block;" total-items="recordCount" items-per-page="pageSize" ng-model="pageIndex" ng-change="pageChanged()" previous-text="<" next-text=">"></pagination>
        <select class="form-control col-sm-2" style="float: left; margin-left: 10px" ng-change="pagingSizeChange()" ng-model="pageSize">
            <option ng-repeat=" size in pageSizes  track by $index">{{size}}</option>
        </select>
        <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right uppercase-text" ng-click="export()" style="margin-right:5px">{{'commonResource.export'|translate}}</a>
    </div>
    <div ng-include src=" 'pages/share/mobileSubscriptionModel.html' "></div>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="ExportMobileSubscriptionsModel">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="cancel()">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">{{'commonResource.export' | translate}}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>{{'mobileSubscriptionResource.export' | translate}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary " ng-disabled="isShowSpinner" style="width:50px;" ng-click="ok()">
                {{ 'commonResource.yes' | translate }}
                <span spinner is-show="isShowSpinner" style="position: absolute;left: 83%;"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancel()" data-translate="commonResource.no"></button>
        </div>
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: where is your `ng-controller`?

Comment: I have no idea. I cant find it. I've tried searching for 'ng-controller="mobileSubscriptionController" and 'ng-controller=mobileSubscriptionDetailCtrl" in the entire solution but nothing shows up. I dont understand how the other functions work, but they do.

Comment: Is your `toggleMobileDetailsInfoHistoryModule()` working?

Comment: @CharbelIlias a script with `ng-template` is like a separate `.html` file. You can insert it into the body with `ng-view`, so `ng-controller` is not needed there, as long as you have `controller : "mobileSubscriptionController"` in `angular.config`

Comment: No, thats the problem. There is several other functions in "mobileSubscriptionDetailCtrl " besides "$scope.cancel", there is "$scope.delete", "$scope.edit" functions, and they all work! Very strange

Comment: Aleksey, yes this much I have figured out also, but its so strange that I cant just add functionality?

Comment: Check your console log, is there any error related to `mobileSubscriptionDetailCtrl`?

Comment: Bharadwaj, there are no errors..

Comment: Try redefining your model controller, instead of using `var` declare `function` directly. And do `$inject` for injecting dependencies.

Comment: Bharadwaj, could you give an example of how you mean, Im not sure I understand fully.

Comment: `mobileSubscriptionDetailCtrl.$injector = [<injectors>]; funtion mobileSubscriptionDetailCtrl(<injectors>){....}`

Comment: Bharadwaj, it didnt do any difference.. It didnt crash or anything, it just worked like it did without it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are not assigning mobileSubscriptionDetailCtrl into angular. Which would be why the controller wouldn't be doing anything. Try changing var  mobileSubscriptionDetailCtrl = 
To
app.controller

Comment: Please be more specific as to what you're suggesting to change.

Comment: I just did. It didnt work. Didnt get any errors or anything, it just behaved like before. Tried refreshing, rebuilding and so on..